# Why is the passive voice more prevalent in English than in other European languages?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice, active-voice, germanic-languages

Although the active voice is predominant in the English language the ‘ideal’ proportion of recommended passive sentences is still regarded as between 5% and 10%([source1](https://www.ego4u.com/en/business-english/grammar/passive)) ( [source2](http://resources.marshalladulteducation.org/techtips/techtip96.htm)). Which is substantially more than in languages like Spanish and, though I couldn't find numerical data to compare the percentage use of the passive voice, experience of writing in Spanish and memories of Spanish teachers accustomed to bilingual students warning about overusing the passive voice "like in English", 
as well as these language learning sites expressing that the passive is not as common in [Spanish](https://www.thoughtco.com/avoiding-the-passive-voice-spanish-3079429), [Italian](http://www.italianlanguageguide.com/grammar/passive-voice.asp) and [German](https://www.thoughtco.com/the-passive-voice-in-german-4068771) as it is in English, provide me with some confirmation.

As such, what intrinsic difference does English have that would allow more sentences  to make sense in the passive voice than the languages mentioned above? Sources would be appreciated.

P.S. It's still gramatically correct in all the languages mentioned above to use the pasive voice to whatever degree, but many more sentences in this voice would be discouraged as they'd simply not make much sense or be very hard to understand (particullarly in conversations).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com. Presuming the accuracy of the statement, it is a great question for linguistics.stackexchange.com (but not for ELU) because it involves the comparison of languages. The answer within English alone is that people speaking English use the passive just the right amount

Comment: It varies a lot from one language to another what counts as "the passive construction". Sometimes there are several, one officially called "passive", along with others that do the same job, like reflexive verbs, which are **very** common in (e.g.) Spanish. This is not a question that can be answered because it is not stated precisely enough.

Comment: Irish and Scots Gaelic use passives quite a lot and have several constructions but I guess when you said "other European languages" you meant "certain European languages often taught as second languages".

Comment: It is difficult to measure how common passives are in a given language as there is enormous variation by register, at least in all the modern languages I know. Academic papers may contain many but the most casual conversation may have as few as two (I was born and raised in...). Certainly these are the only two synthetic passives you need to learn to have a conversation in Scots Gaelic.

Comment: This interesting subject  comes up from time to time. The usual reaction from NS is that it is probably not true. It is more an impression that NNS have.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, passive voice is far more used in German than in English. In my experience with German language this is so, and you can also find a lot of information about the topic in multiple links on the website.

Comment: I'd be sceptical about language teachers saying such and such a construction is used less - from what I've seen, a teacher will often notice that learners tend to use a construction when it is not appropriate in the language they are learning, and conclude that is must be used more in their native language, when all that really follows is that is used in different situations. They overlook the situations where it would be used in their language but not in the student's native language.

Comment: I'd say you have to look at the function of the passive in different languages, how often a need for something to perform that function comes up, and what other devices could be used instead. All these things are likely to vary from one language to another.

Comment: @Minty I wouldn't be so skeptical, there are languages after all where the passive voice isn't possible and this has to do with the structure of the language. It's possible then that for reasons like the one given below by "vectory" (though I'm not sure that's the correct one) the passive voice would sound awkward or make the sentence even longer than in English, thus discouraging it's use.

Comment: but those reasons are the ones I gave...

Comment: I didn't see your comment...

Comment: I'll ask this question on linguistics stack exchange maybe it was a mistake putting it on the english one

Answer (score 1):

English does often not mark noun phrases for oblique cases. As such, the objects of an action may look like the subject and appear in subject position

You cannot even tell whether it's active or passive in "Alice was driven".

Comment: I would argue that the sentence "Alice was driven" is definitely in the passive voice. It has at least four possible meanings (someone drove a vehicle in which she was a passenger, someone forced her to walk in a particular direction, she was forced by circumstances into a particular course of action, and she was compelled by her own psychology or upbringing into working exceptionally hard) but, even in the last of these, the language suggests that her ambition was separate from her concious mind and was, therefore, an external force in that sense.

Comment: @BoldBen You missed a very important meaning: *Alice was* ***(determined / passionate)***.

Comment: @JasonBassford For me that's a shorter way of saying that she was compelled by her own psychology etc. The passion and determination are effects of the psychological condition.